# CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project): No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found

Tags: python-2.7, cmake, android-sdk-tools, gradlew

I am facing an issue with Gradle Wrapper build samples. Issue related to CMAKE.
Following versions of software currently installed in my system.

- python version: 2.7.18 (as it is required for the project).
- cmake version 3.22.6.
- Java version: 11.0.16.1 2022-08-12 LTS.
- Visual Studio 2022 community with C++  2012 development tools Redistributable (x64) installed.
- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER set to 2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe.
- Android version SDK build tools 34 installed.

It fails with the following output:.

```
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
 CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Tried installing different compatible versions.

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` should be set either to the **absolute path** or to the **name of the program**, which could be found in a directory listed in `PATH`. But you assign a value `2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe` which is neither of them.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe. This path was added to system variables. but still receiving the error.

Comment: But the error was slightly different this time.                                                    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

Comment: Please, [edit] the question post and update the content of the variable and error message. On Stack Overflow a **question post** itself should contain all relevant information about the problem. (In other words, for answer a question one shouldn't read the comments below it).